# How should I handle page refreshes in EmberJS?

Tags: ember.js

As I understand from the [EmberJS Guide to Routing](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/#toc_asynchronously-loading-models), you should specify the model you want a route to load in the `Route`'s `model` hook. The model hook may return a promise, and if it does, the route will pause until the promise resolves.

*Therein lies my problem*: this approach works fantastically under normal use cases (user triggers a transition from any other route into the route in question.) The problem arises if the user is currently at the route in question.

If the user triggers a page refresh (using the browser's refresh button, or `ctrl+r` or whatever other trigger there might be, the `promise` in the `model` hook causes the user to sit at a blank white page until that promise returns. In large dataset cases, this can be a handful of seconds, which does not make for a great user experience.

**So, how do I resolve this issue?**

The only solution I have developed is to trigger the data load in the route's `activate` hook, and manually set the controller's model when that promise returns. I don't like doing this, because I'm circumventing the entirety of Ember's model framework.

I would like the `application` template to render before the `model` hook hangs the page, at a bare minimum. Any guidance on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

In case the context is necessary: as the tags imply, I am using Ember-Data. I'm utilizing the RESTAdapter almost entirely out-of-the-box, unmodified.

Answer (score 1):

Routes have sub-states that can be used to render a temporary template while the model is loading. See: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/

The first load/initial blank page is a UX problem that will be solved by Fast Boot, see: http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/12/22/inside-fastboot-the-road-to-server-side-rendering.html

Fast boot is already available through one of Ember's branches, I don't know the name.